# Click to email button not working on android

Tags: android, email, button

Hello can someone please tell me how to create an click to email button that works on android? I have tried this (with mailto):

```
<input type="submit" value="Send Mileage" onclick="sendMileage()" />
```

.

```
 function sendMileage() {
      window.open('mailto:email@yahoo.com?subject=subject&body=body');
    }
```

This works fine on my PC but when I put it on my appsbar app, download the app on android and then press the button it doesn't work, and says 'Web page not available'.

Can someone please tell me how to get this button to work on android?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by using:

```
window.location = "mailto:email@yahoo.com?subject=subject&body=body"
```

Comment: The same thing happens.